# Request parameters in ExactTarget postMessageContact/Send REST API method

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

We have integrated an app to send out transactional SMS messages to defined mobile numbers using the [MessageContact/Send SMS REST API method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html). The problem is that this method isn't documented very well. Finally after trial and error, I discovered that in order to send an SMS, the mobile number needs to be subscribed to a keyword.

[image: MobileConnect Subscriptions]

Here's my request:

```
{
    "mobileNumbers": [
    "61400000000"
    ],
    "Subscribe": true,
    "Resubscribe": false,
    "Keyword": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "Override": true,
    "messageText": "Hello world"
}
```

Can someone explain what these key-value pairs represent? Here's what I am guessing:

- **mobileNumbers**: array of mobile numbers
- **Subscribe**: adds `mobileNumbers` as a contact (go to MobileConnect > Manage Contacts)
- **Resubscribe**: absolutely no idea
- **Keyword**: a valid 'keyword' that has been created in MobileConnect (but why this is required, for one-way SMS, I'm not sure)
- **Override**: overrides the template text message with `messageText`
- **messageText**: message you want to send

I'd appreciate if someone could provide some clarity around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this clears things up a bit -

- **mobileNumbers**: you are correct - this is an array of the mobile numbers you will be sending the message to.
- **Subscribe**: true/false value - use this if you want non subscribers to be subscribed. Set to false if you don't want to add new subscribers.
- **Resubscribe**: if someone has opted out, setting this to true will opt them back in.
- **Keyword**: if subscribe/resubscribe are set to true, this is the key word in your account that is used to subscribe them - you could have multiple subscribe message based on individual campaigns or something
- **Override**: set this to true if you want to update the message sent at send time
- **messageText**: if you set override to true, you will add your send time message here.